# while adding multiple columns in table giving error in sql ser

Tags: sql, sql-server, default-value, ddl

getting error while adding multiple coloumns in a table

> ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls,
>      or have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is
>      an identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the
>      previous conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow
>      addition of this column. Column 'Country' cannot be added to
>      non-empty table 'tbl_alerts' because it does not satisfy these
>      conditions.

Here is my `alter table` statement

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_alerts
         ADD 
        Country [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        StateName [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        City [varchar](50) NOT NULL, 
        MacAddress [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        OSDetails [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        MachineName [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        Browser [varchar](50) NOT NULL
```

Comment: When adding a non-nullable column, you should specify a default value.

Comment: The problem is that *already existing rows* of the table would end up having a new `NOT NULL` column without any values in it.

Comment: Why don't people ever read the error message? It's there so that you could know what went wrong! it's plain English, so other then translating it to your native language, I don't know how can someone answer your question better then the error message have already did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your table already contains rows and you are attempting to add `not null` columns without a default value. In this case, the database has no way of knowing what values to fill those columns with, and since they must have values (they're defined as `not null`), it will fail.

One way to solve this is to add default values to the column specifications:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_alerts
    ADD 
    Country [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USA',
    StateName [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NY',
    City [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NY', 
    MacAddress [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '68:f7:28:40:e8:b4',
    OSDetails [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Fedora 21',
    MachineName [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MyComputer',
    Browser [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Firefox'
```